# nginx - server from single directory for nested path

Tags: nginx, url-rewrite-module, nginx-location

I have set default root directory as $root to listen on port 80.

Now I want to serve from different directory (share1) if path is started with /user i.e. /user ,  /user/xyz ,  /user/abc all should be serve from  share1 directory..

```
map $http_user_agent $root {
    "~*android" /home/vishant/devcenter/wava-v1.1/android;
    "~iPhone" /home/vishant/devcenter/wava-v1.1/ios;
    default  /home/vishant/devcenter/wava-v1.1/ios;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    root $root;
    index index.html;

    location /user {
           alias /home/vishant/devcenter/share1;
    }
}
```

In short i want something like below..though it's not correct...

```
location /user/* {
    alias /home/vishant/devcenter/share1;
}
```

**I want all the request starting with /user (/user/abc , /user/xyz) should hit the index.html file.**

Answer (score 0):

To make it clear and working you can divide main `/` and `/user` root.

```
map $http_user_agent $root {
    "~*android" /home/vishant/devcenter/wava-v1.1/android;
    "~iPhone" /home/vishant/devcenter/wava-v1.1/ios;
    default  /home/vishant/devcenter/wava-v1.1/ios;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        root $root;
        index index.html;
    }

    location /user {
        alias /home/vishant/devcenter/share1;

        rewrite ^(.*)$ /user/index.html last;
    }
}
```

It should match everything starting with `/user` and alias to specified path.

Comment: tried implementing this.. but didn't work.. /user/abc still get 404 Not Found

Comment: does the file exist then? ;)

Comment: i have only index.html file & i want to call index.html. not others.

Comment: Then add rewrite rule, added example to answer.

Comment: tried your solution but didn't work...  same 404 Not Found :(

Comment: i have created another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39745315/nginx-redirect-subdirectories-path-to-single-index-html-file). it might looks easy..