# nginx - redirect subdirectories path to single (index.html) file

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-location

How to redirect all the sub directory path to single index.html file?

here is what i want nginx configuration:

```
location /user/* {
    alias /home/vishant/devcenter/baetter-share1;
    index index.html;
}
```

this means if i hit /user OR /user/vishant OR /user/xyz/vishant it should render only index.html page.

The code i have written is not working but what i thought should be similar to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
location /user/ {
    root /home/vishant/devcenter/baetter-share1;
    try_files /index.html =404;
}
```

Documentation:

- [location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)
- [root](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root)
- [try_files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)